# Warning:No JDK specified for module 'Myproject'.when run my project in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run my project, I found the module in error
then I click in founding an error **"Warning:No JDK specified for module 'Myproject**'.when run my project.",vI setting `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` in my path. hope Anyone can share your idea?

Comment: check if you have installed the correct jdk

Comment: I am sure the jdk is right install, version jdk1.8

Comment: it also gives problem if you have 64 bit os and have installed 32 bit jdk

Comment: my os 64bit and jdk also 64bit, i think maybe the module seeting is wrong,but i can not find the error .

Comment: right-click on your project and select "open module settings" and check whether it specifies the correct JDK location there ..

Comment: related?: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-21480

Answer (score 49):

it happened for me when I deleted the jdk and installed new one somehow the project kept seeing the old one as invalid but couldn't change, so right click on your module -> Open Module Settings -> and choose Compile Sdk Version.

Comment: i would have to do that for 150 modules. wtf

Comment: It happened to me on MacOs after installing a new JDK (even do the project was using the Android studio one) -> del .idea folder and re-import solved it.

Answer (score 44):

Go to File->Project Structure->SDK Location and check if the path for SDK and JDK location specified by you is correct. If its not then set the correct path. Then It will work.

Answer (score 20):

Restart intelliJ and import project as maven if it is a maven project

Comment: It solved my problem, I also Answer here. Great Amit

Comment: Invalidating the cache solved my problem

Answer (score 17):

Run -> Edit configurations -> Select your build configuration -> JRE - change Default to one of actual JDK paths

Answer (score 9):

Restart IntelliJ and reimport the Project and import it as maven. It should work then. The error occurs because IntelliJ keeps track of module through .iml files so any changes in these files can cause this error. Reimporting the project regenerates the .iml file so generally, it solves the error.

Comment: Invalidating cache worked for me. File > Invalidate Cache > only selected Clear file System cache and Local history

Answer (score 6):

ReImport the dependencies if it is a maven project

Comment: Worked for Gradle as well. :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem running a simple java projet in Intellij, getting the ,message:
"java: JDK isn't specified for module 'my module' "
I resolved it, I followed these steps:

- Right click on the module name (*my module*)
- Click **Open Module Settings**
- Open the tab **Dependencies**
- Under **Module SDK**,change the SDK version
- Click OK and rerun

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** Restart IntelliJ Idea as mentioned in the screenshot attached, if you are using eclipse jee ide then just right-click on the project and click on the restart button

[image]

**Step 2:** just clean and install the maven

**Step 3:** Run your tomcat server again. **Yahoo!!! Worked Perfect**

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions or if there's anything else I can assist you with.

Happy coding! ‍

Answer (score 2):

Syncing Gradle fixed this issue for me.

Comment: you may try File | Invalid caches and Restart as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it using the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176571/1174024 
But I have 150 modules. So I would have had to perform this step 150 times.

So I needed to do it a different way.

So first close the existing project, then Import it again, In the first step of the wizard choose "Gradle" project. Then the next step of the wizard has the Gradle project properties. Here it's going to ask you for, among other things, the Java SDK to use. The default will be "Project SDK". Do not use this default, instead hand pick your Java SDK from the list. Then finish the import.

Now the problem should go away.

Comment: for me, delete the .idea and re-importing was enough. I kept the project SDK config.

Comment: yeah that sounds like it would be effective.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux I've resolved this by deleting all the folders with names starting as ".AndroidStudio" in my home directory and then rerunning the Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I ended up re-importing the entire project to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Intellij, right click on pom.xml and Maven > Unlink project.
Then reload the project by right clicking the pom.xml file again

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by simply refreshing the modules View > Maven Projects. There is refresh icon which refreshes your entire project(s)

***How I got this error*** : I imported a project (Let's call this A which is main project) first and added the remaining projects (B,C,D etc) as modules to this one as I needed all my projects to be shown in one package folder. I deleted the old (A) Project and cloned it again from repo.
The IntelliJ reloaded the (A) project but when I try to run, the project wasn't compiling saying "Warning:No JDK specified for module 'B'".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using **ionic capacitor**. After running the command `npx cap open android` I tried to run the app on my device using android studio, but the Gradle was syncing in the background so I was getting this error. Just let the Gradle sync and app building process finish and then run the app.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me for apparently no good reasons. I invalidated the cache and restarted the project and thus, the issue was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating cache and restarting IDE may fix this issue in InteliJ

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This fix helps me :

1. Open "SDK Manager" on the top right side -> "SDK Tools" -> select the API version that causes error.
2. In my case , the studio shown pop up message like "**no jdk specified for module 'android.app.main' in android 11**"
3. So just **UnSelected** the particular build tools version , then clicked Apply -> OK
4. After a couple of mins, the gradle sync completed successfully
5. Then installed app on target device.

Answer (score 0):

The APK I was testing only worked with Android SDK v28, so the project was never going to run properly until I created a virtual device with a v28 SDK.

Then selecting `File > Project Structure > Project > SDK` = `Android Studio default JDK` solved the error for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me, except deleting the complaining library from maven local cache ($HOME/.m2/repository) and reinstalling it.

Answer (score -1):

Add JDK as depicted in picture

[image]