# Problem with debugging APK with Android Studio 3.1.4 on Windows

Tags: android

After selecting “Profile or Debug APK…” to open an existing APK, pressing the “Debug” button gets us to the “Edit Configuration“ windows with the “Error: Please select Android SDK” message.

[image]

If we still select “Debug”, and then select “Continue Anyway” in the “Change Configuration Settings” windows, the error notification from the main window is “Error running ‘com.appname’: No JDK specified for module ‘com. appname’”.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138737/warningno-jdk-specified-for-module-myproject-when-run-my-project-in-android-s

Comment: Yes, my question was based on 2 different questions on SDK and JDK, but I realized that the SDK and JDK problems are linked.

Answer (score 20):

I found the solution for myself. There are 2 places to check if the SDK was set correctly.

1. File-> Project Structure… -> Project Settings -> Project
   Ensure that Java SDK is set under “Project SDK”. (for example, ‘9.0.1 (java version “9.0.1”)’)
   [Project Settings -> Project (tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/704ex.png)
2. File-> Project Structure… -> Project Settings -> Modules ->  -> Dependencies
   Ensure that your installed Android SDK platform is set under “Module SDK”. (for example, Android API 27 Platform (java version “9.0.1”)’)
   [Project Settings -> Modules (tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hd51.png)

If the application is debuggable, pressing the “Debug” button will bring up the Android emulator selection windows.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me! The point 2. was the main problem! Many thanks!